# Crispy forms field_class not applying correctly

Tags: html, django, django-forms, bootstrap-5, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django form in which I use crispy-forms along with bootstrap5. Everything was alright until I wanted to changed the Layout of my form. As my form is constructed dynamically, I just wanted to define the value of a set element `item` which is under the form `(field_name, layout_index)`. The goal was to define it as a `FieldWithButton`, as I couldn't find another way to do that.

To do that, I modified my helper in the `__init__` method of my form :

```py
self.helper[item[1]] = Div(FieldWithButtons(item[0], StrictButton("Add item")), id=f'div_id_{item[0]}', css_class='mb-3 row')
```

This is rendered nearly correctly in my form, I have the FieldWithButton with Div etc. However, the div which contains my FieldWithButton doesn't take the `field_class` of my helper that I defined, and instead creates a `<divclass='col-10'>...</divclass='col-10'>`.

There's juste a space which disappeared and messed everything up. How can I either remove the `class='col-10'` part of my div and put it as its class or differently define my Field as a FieldWithButton ?

Here's my whole form class if needed :

```py
class ScriptInputForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        variables = kwargs.pop('variables') # All variables to render 
        variables_names = [*variables]      # under the form {'name':['type', 'description']}

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for var in variables_names: # Dynamic creation of the fields
            values = variables[var]
            field = self.fields[var] = forms.CharField()
            field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = values[1].title()

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

        num = 1 # Rough part where I define the tuples ('name', 'index') of all lists in my variables
        lists = []
        for k,v in variables.items():
            if v[0]=='list':
                lists.append((k,num))
            num+=1

        for item in lists: # Part where the problem is coming from
            self.helper[item[1]] = Div(FieldWithButtons(item[0], StrictButton("Add item"))) 

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'),)
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-10'

        self.helper.form_action = reverse_lazy('scripts:data_input')
```

And the rendered HTML :

```
<div> 
    <div class="mb-3 row"> 
        <label for="id_liste" class="col-form-label col-2">Liste</label>
        <divclass="col-10"> <!-- With <div class="col-10"> everything's ok -->
            <div class="input-group"> 
                <input type="text" name="liste" placeholder="Your List" class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_liste"> 
                    <button class="btn" type="button">Add item</button> 
            </div> 
        </divclass="col-10">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, what is this `<divclass="col-10'>` there should be a space between div and class, it might be possible you made  a typo while writing the question, kindly check it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole point of my question, the problem is that it's not a typo but the issue I encountered, the space is not rendered in the html for a reason I couldn't explain. And it seems to come from the definition of `self.helper.field_class = 'col-10'` since if I remove this line I no longer have the problem